# Expected value of $\max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ with $X_1, ..., X_n$ being i.i.d. and the distribution is already known

Tags: probability-theory

So, when the $X_1, ..., X_n$ are uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$, is it allowed to assume that $\max\{X_1, ..., X_n\} = X_k$ without loss of generality and then calculate that $E(\max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}) = (a+b)/2$?

Like, it doesn't matter which one is the maximum because they're all uniformly distributed on the same intervall. And would it be the same argument if we would look at $\min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$?

Comment: This obviously can't work because it would imply the maximum exceeds $X_1$ by an average of $0$, even though the difference is non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each $X_i$ has CDF $F(x)$, $X_\max:=\max_i X_i$ has CDF $P(X_i\le x)=F(x)^n$, from which a mean is in principle calculable. In the problem at hand, the result is $\int_0^1x(x^n)^\prime dx=\frac{n}{n+1}$ if $a=0,\,b=1$, or more generally $a+\frac{n}{n+1}(b-a)=b-\frac{b-a}{n+1}=\frac{a+nb}{n+1}$ by linearity.